# Specifying multiple Spring configuration files using ant style pattern in command line app

Tags: spring

I have a web application with mutiple Spring configuration files. These files are loaded using "contextConfigLocation" in web.xml. Like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:META-INF/*beans.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Everything works as desired.

Now I am having to write a command line application that must load the same files as the web application. Currently I am using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and manually specifying each configuration file name. But sooner or later somebody is going to add another file and expect it to be read by the CLI, just like the web app. Currently that will not happen because each file is explicitly specified in my CLI. So I need my CLI to load configuration files just like the web app i.e. load all configuration files that match a pattern. Is there a way to do this using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, This will load any context file that is in class path ending with name **Beans**

```
public class LoadContext {

/**
 * @param args
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:*Beans.xml");
  }

 }
```

Comment: You are correct. `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/*beans.xml");` loads all the bean configuration files ending beans.xml. Note that the "classpath:" had to be removed to get it working. 

Thank you for the suggestion Prasanna Talakanti.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new configuration file `spring-all.xml` and load only this.  In this file, use the `import` element to import all other xml configuration files that you need.

```
<beans>
    <import resource="spring-services.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-daos.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-controllers.xml"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

Comment: I am afraid this only moves the problem out of the .java file on to a new .xml file i.e. when a new configuration file gets added, care must be taken to add the new file name in spring-all.xml. The desired solution is to have the configuration file follow a naming convention and have it read without repeating the name elsewhere.